# Can some help me with this problem please.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How can I prove that there is a positive integer that can be written as the sum of squares of positive integers.

Comment: $1 = 1^2$. Are you sure this is what your question is?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could just give an example.

$$25 = 3^2 + 4^2$$

But alternatively, you could say that for some sequence of postive integers $s$, the sum of the squares of those integers is $\sum s_n^2$. As long as $s_n$ is of finite length, $\sum s_n^2$ will have a finite answer, which will itself be the sum of the squares of those positive integers (by definition).

For example:

$$ s := \lbrace 2, 6, 12, 13 \rbrace\\
\sum s_n^2 = 2^2 + 6^2 + 12^2 + 13^2 = 353$$

Thus, $353$ is "a positive integer that can be written as the sum of squares of positive integers."

As Julien asks, are you sure this is what you're trying to ask?

Comment: The question need to prove, it doesn't asked for an example but you gave the idea of what the question mean....thankyou

Comment: If I asked you to prove that dogs exist, you could do so by bringing me a dog. Likewise, if you ask me to prove that a number according to the given conditions exists, I can do so by showing you that number.